# Set break points in Tornado app

Tags: debugging, python-2.7, tornado

How could I set a break point in my tornado app? 
I tried pdb, but Tornado app seams to be ignoring my pdb.set_trace() command in my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running your app using foreman you would set you environment variable in .env file in root project folder. 
Setting the below env variable in my .env file did the tick form me.

PYTHONUNBUFFERED=true

Now I can set code breakpoints in my app, and also print output to server logs while running the app using foreman.

Answer (score 2):

Where did you put `pdb.set_trace()`...? This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import pdb 

from tornado.options import define, options
define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        greeting = self.get_argument('greeting', 'Hello')
        reself.write(greeting + ', friendly user!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/", IndexHandler)])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    pdb.set_trace()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Session:

```
$ python test.py
> /home/mariusz/Dokumenty/Projekty/Testy/test.py(24)<module>()
-> tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
(Pdb) break 16
Breakpoint 1 at /home/mariusz/Dokumenty/Projekty/Testy/test.py:16
(Pdb) continue
> /home/mariusz/Dokumenty/Projekty/Testy/test.py(16)get()
-> self.write(greeting + ', friendly user!')
(Pdb) step
--Call--
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py(497)write()
-> def write(self, chunk):
(Pdb) step
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py(512)write()
-> if self._finished:
(Pdb) step
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py(516)write()
-> if isinstance(chunk, dict):
(Pdb)
```

After putting `continue` in above code debugger stopped, because I had to poll `http://localhost:8000/` in browser to have `RequestHandler` function actually called.

Comment: I am actually using Foreman to run my Tornado app. I guess its Foreman which ignore the break points.